# jQuery Orbit not working with .slideToggle()

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle, orbit

I have a jQuery Orbit slider within a SECTION that is hidden by default (display:none;)

The user clicks on a button to expand the SECTION, and upon doing so, I see that only the left directional nav arrow shows up, the rest of the Orbit slider appears to be invisible.

If I remove the display:none; on the SECTION so that the default behaviour of the SECTION is that it is expanded upon first visit, I can .slideToggle up and down and the Orbit slider shows up just fine. It only has problems when it is sitting within the SECTION with display:none; set.

Here is the markup:
http://pastie.org/2855132

Here is the jQuery:
http://pastie.org/2855138

All of the Orbit styles are default. It is section.articles that is set to display:none;

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I hope I have provided enough information.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    $(".banner").click(function() {
    $(this).next(".articles").slideToggle("slow", function(){

        $('#featured').orbit({
            animationSpeed: 800,
            timer: false,
            captions: false
        });


    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but given this was posted so long ago, I've since moved on. Flexslider is now my preferred jQuery slider. Highly recommend it!